# Android Studio FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Приложение вылетает при запуске.

```
`07-24 14:12:25.557 21315-21315/com.example.msi.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.msi.myapplication, PID: 21315
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:161)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.remove(AbstractList.java:374)
    at java.util.AbstractList.removeRange(AbstractList.java:571)
    at java.util.AbstractList.clear(AbstractList.java:234)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.clear(ArrayAdapter.java:328)
    at com.example.msi.myapplication.MainActivity$3.onItemSelected(MainActivity.java:107)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:944)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:933)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.access$300(AdapterView.java:53)
    at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:898)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)`
```

Фрагмент кода:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, active);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            val1 = activeVals[position];
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView){
        }
    });

    Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            val2 = activeVals[position];
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView){}
    });

    Spinner spin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
    TitleSpinner customAdapter = new TitleSpinner(getApplicationContext(),titleIcons,titles);
    spin.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            activeVals = accordanceVals[position];
            adapter.clear();
            adapter.addAll(accordance[position]);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView){}
    });
}
```

Comment: При комментировании adapter.clear и adapter.addAll все нормально. Т.е. думаю, что проблема в них

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Вы создаёте адаптер из массива либо неизменяемого списка - поэтому операции, изменяющие количество элементов не поддерживаются.
Нужно либо самому создать нормальный список и с ним создавать адаптер, либо создать пустой адаптер, а данные добавить потом

```
// первый вариант
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(stringArray));
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
```

---

```
// второй вариант
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.addAll(stringArray);
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает